# create accessible tabs using bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accessibility

I am creating a accessible site on bootstrap 3 but my problem is that tabs are not accessible.
how can i make tabs accessible.MY code is like this.Screen Reader reading it like link list

```
 <div class="tabbable">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#pane1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pane2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pane3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pane4" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a></li>
  </ul> 
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="pane1" class="tab-pane active">
    <h4>The Markup</h4>
  <pre>Code here ...</pre>
</div>
<div id="pane2" class="tab-pane">
<h4>Pane 2 Content</h4>
  <p> and so on ...</p>
</div>
<div id="pane3" class="tab-pane">
  <h4>Pane 3 Content</h4>
</div>
<div id="pane4" class="tab-pane">
  <h4>Pane 4 Content</h4>
</div>
</div><!-- /.tab-content -->
```

Comment: Welcome on SO! Have you heard of the [Bootstrap accessibility plugin](https://www.paypal-engineering.com/2014/01/28/bootstrap-accessibility-plugin-making-the-popular-web-development-framework-better/) from Paypal developers? Might be handy (it's very recent and I didn't test it yet)

Comment: i already added it but tabs are not accessible

Comment: Wait, how is reading a tab menu like a link list a problem? Most of them are coded like that, Bootstrap or not. If you want to improve it, you'll have to manage it with WAI-ARIA (`tablist` component)

Comment: yes it is reading like a link list

Comment: FelipeAls thanks for help WAI-ARIA Worked